# Understanding IsLive and Storage Class while writing Object Lifecycle rules in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, versioning

We need to enable below `Object Lifecycle rules` in `GCP Cloud Storage bucket`

1. If a ***non current object version*** is not accessed for 100 days and its current storage class is either of `STORAGE, MULTI_REGIONAL and DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY` , move that object to `Nearline` Storage
2. If a object version is not accessed for 100 days and its current storage class is `Nearline` , move it to `Coldline` storage Class
3. Delete from `Coldline` storage if objects are not accessed for 100 days from `Coldline` Storage.
4. Keep 2 non current version of file

To implement the above rules , the following rules were applied to bucket

```
{
 "lifecycle": {
   "rule": [
   {
    "action": {
    "type": "SetStorageClass",
    "storageClass": "NEARLINE"
 },
 "condition": {
    "age": 100,
    "isLive": false,
    "matchesStorageClass": ["REGIONAL", "STANDARD", "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"]
    }
   },
  {
    "action": {
    "type": "SetStorageClass",
    "storageClass": "COLDLINE"
    },
     "condition": {
       "age": 100,
       "matchesStorageClass": ["NEARLINE"]
      }
  },
 {
   "action": { "type": "Delete"},
    "condition": {
     "age": 100,
     "matchesStorageClass": ["COLDLINE"]
    }
   },
  {
    "action": { "type": "Delete"},
     "condition": {
     "numNewerVersions": 2
     }
    }
   ]
   }
   }
```

Need clarification on below

1. It is showing the rules are applied successfully but will it work practically. Since we are  moving non current versions from **NEARLINE** to **COLDLINE** which are not accessed for 100 days do I need to add  "isLive": false in Rule 2 . Also does we need it for rule 3 too .

   ```
   {
    "action": {
    "type": "SetStorageClass",
    "storageClass": "COLDLINE"
    },
     "condition": {
       "age": 100,
       "isLive": false
       "matchesStorageClass": ["NEARLINE"]
      }
   ```

   },

   ```
   {
     "action": { "type": "Delete"},
     "condition": {
     "age": 100,
     "isLive": false
     "matchesStorageClass": ["COLDLINE"]
    }
   },
   ```
2. Also does it makes sense to move directly to **COLDLINE** from **STANDARD** storage class as we are considering access above 100 days

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules aren't correct.

Firstly, the `age` is the [number of days after the creation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#age)

> Age is measured from the object's creation time

So, your condition "if it has not been accessed the last 100 days" is not possible. The correct expression is "100 days after its creation, do..."

From there, your archiving policies aren't correct. You use the same age (100 days after the object creation) to

- Go to Nearline
- Go to Coldline
- Delete from Cold line

On the same AGE condition!!

---

To answer to your questions

1. No, you don't need to mention the `isLive: false` if you consider (and you are sure) that only non-current version are in `nearline` class
2. Yes you can jump from standard to Coldline, especially for the non-current versions if you consider them as never (or very rarely) used, and then delete them after 100 days.

Comment: Thanks . So rules are based on ' Age' and not 'access` . Few queries..Once a non current file is moved from STANDARD to NEARLINE OR COLDLINE , looks like the creation date is not modified so "Age" has to be "100" , "200" and "300" respectively in the first three rules . Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: It's correct. When you change the storage class, you update the blob metadata, but not the blob itself, and thus the creation date doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks . Also will it be safe to add `isLive: false` In Rule 2 and 3 if there are chances that Live! versions will be there along with non current versions in NEARLINE and COLDLINE storage which are moved from STORAGE class. ?

Comment: Yes it will be safer!